# Lookup resource servers with OpenID Connect / OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We are planning to use OpenID Connect / OAuth2 to handle access to a list of resource servers.

We want to use JWT as access token when a user is going to call one of the resource servers. The access token will be issued by an auth server in our landscape according to OpenId Connect / OAuth2 standards. Access will be granted or rejected to the calling user based on the JWT access token.

The standards are new for us so we are still reading and understanding.

We are currently searching for an option to do a lookup of the resource servers with a call to auth server. We would like to use it in order to simplify the clients.

Is there any option available in OpenId Connect / OAuth2 to help clients finding the available resource server? Is there any endpoint available in auth server to do that? Or can the answer with the JWT be enhanced to return the list of the resource servers?

Thanks in advance
Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

With the use of `JWT`, there is no need to go for one extra validation from the `authorization server`. Token & its claims should be enough to validate the access rights. You can customized the token claims as per the needs.

Comment: Maybe you didn't get me right. I understood that there are different option to validate the JWT. And some of them do not require the resource servers to call the auth server.

I should asked my question more precisely. Does the standard support any means by which a client can lookup the available resource servers? We have a list of servers and we need some lookup for our clients that are going to call them.

Maybe it is possible to lookup the available resource servers in the auth server somehow?

Answer (score 0):

An Authorization Server does not know the list of APIs, since APIs are not usually registered as clients. There are some related concepts though. The [IAM Primer](https://curity.io/resources/learn/iam-primer/) article has a good overview on how these concepts fit together.

- Each API covers an area of data and this maps neatly to the [OAuth Scopes](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) included in access tokens.
- Each API has an audience, such as `api.mycompany.com`, which maps to the `aud` claim in an access token. This can enable related APIs to forward the same access token to each other and securely maintain the original caller's identity.
- An API gateway is usually hosted in front of APIs, as a hosting best practice. This enables clients to use a single, easy to manage, API base URL, such as https://api.mycompany.com, followed by a logical path.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a closer look to your description and the links provided.